# Which one should be chosen: "will - are going to"?

Tags: word-choice, future

> Liverpool's players are skilled, so they .... the match easily.

1. will win
2. are going to win

I had hard time answering this question in my final exam in the High School, my answer was ***the second***. Some of my classmates said: "will win".

Comment: (This is also seems like somebody asking the same homework question as in [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/501653/will-vs-going-to) from three hours earlier.)

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is that you can use either *will* or *are going to*. Perhaps **they are going to win the match** is more like a prediction, and **they will win the match** suggests you have seen the future!

The question has been asked before, [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193090/can-i-use-be-going-to-instead-of-will-in-this-situation). You may find the answer and the comments useful.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my answer. 
Both of this 2 options are correct ( based on the hint of context provided on your exam)

1. Are going to win = you planned everthing to be a winner and you predict you can win that in your future.
2. Will win = you might have no plan for winning that but you trust in your ability to win and you said I WILL win this. Dont be confused will as the future tense because there is no future tense. Its just a name.